# Linear Algebra determinant reduction 2

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\begin{vmatrix}
x &x^2  &1+x^3 \\ 
y &y^2  &1+y^3 \\ 
z &z^2  &1+z^3 
\end{vmatrix}=0$, then prove, without expansion, that $xyz=-1$, where $x,y,z$ are not equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
x &x^2  &1+x^3 \\ 
y &y^2  &1+y^3 \\ 
z &z^2  &1+z^3 
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{vmatrix}
x &x^2  &1 \\ 
y &y^2  &1 \\ 
z &z^2  &1 
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
x &x^2  &x^3 \\ 
y &y^2  &y^3 \\ 
z &z^2  &z^3 
\end{vmatrix}$$

Again,
$$\begin{vmatrix}
x &x^2  &x^3 \\ 
y &y^2  &y^3 \\ 
z &z^2  &z^3 
\end{vmatrix}=xyz \begin{vmatrix}
1 &x  &x^2 \\ 
1 &y  &y^2 \\ 
1 &z  &z^2 
\end{vmatrix}
=xyz \begin{vmatrix}
x  &1&x^2 \\ 
y  &1&y^2 \\ 
z  &1&z^2 
\end{vmatrix}(-1)
=xyz \begin{vmatrix}
x  &x^2&1 \\ 
y  &y^2&1 \\ 
z  &z^2&1 
\end{vmatrix}(-1)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Using multilinearity and alternativity of the determinant:

$$0=\begin{vmatrix}
x &x^2  &1+x^3 \\ 
y &y^2  &1+y^3 \\ 
z &z^2  &1+z^3 
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
x &x^2  &1 \\ 
y &y^2  &1 \\ 
z &z^2  &1
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
x &x^2  &x^3 \\ 
y &y^2  &y^3 \\ 
z &z^2  &z^3 
\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$=\begin{vmatrix}
x &x^2  &1 \\ 
y &y^2  &1 \\ 
z &z^2  &1 
\end{vmatrix}+xyz\begin{vmatrix}
1 &x  &x^2 \\ 
1 &y  &y^2 \\ 
1 &z  &z^2 
\end{vmatrix}=\ldots$$

and now complete the exercise.