# Determinant reduction problem

Tags: linear-algebra

If a,b,c are all different and $\displaystyle \begin{vmatrix}
a &a^3  &a^4-1 \\ 
b &b^3  &b^4-1 \\ 
c &c^3  &c^4-1
\end{vmatrix}=0$, then show that abc(bc+ca+ab)=a+b+c.

I try to separate column3 into its components,
$\displaystyle \begin{vmatrix}
a &a^3  &a^4 \\ 
b &b^3  &b^4 \\ 
c &c^3  &c^4
\end{vmatrix}$-$\displaystyle \begin{vmatrix}
a &a^3  &1 \\ 
b &b^3  &1 \\ 
c &c^3  &1
\end{vmatrix}$

take out abc from 1st matrix .. then I get stuck..

Any hints?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806876/linear-algebra-determinant-reduction-2

Comment: Have you tried subtracting rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle D=\begin{vmatrix}
a &a^3  &a^4 \\ 
b &b^3  &b^4 \\ 
c &c^3  &c^4
\end{vmatrix}=abc\begin{vmatrix}
1 &a^2  &a^3 \\ 
1 &b^2  &b^3 \\ 
1 &c^2  &c^3
\end{vmatrix}$

Setting $R_2'=R_2-R_1, R_3'=R_3-R_1$

$\displaystyle D=abc\begin{vmatrix}
1 &a^2  &a^3 \\ 
0 &b^2-a^2  &b^3-a^3 \\ 
0 &c^2-a^2  &c^3-a^3
\end{vmatrix}=abc(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}
1 &a^2  &a^3 \\ 
0 &b+a  &b^2+ab+a^2 \\ 
0 &c+a  &c^2+ca+a^2
\end{vmatrix}$

Setting $C_3'=C_3-a\cdot C_2$

$\displaystyle D=abc(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}
1 &a^2  &0 \\ 
0 &b+a  &b^2 \\ 
0 &c+a  &c^2
\end{vmatrix}$

Setting $R_2'=R_2-a\cdot R_3$

$\displaystyle D=abc(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}
1 &a^2  &0 \\ 
0 &b-c  &b^2-c^2 \\ 
0 &c+a  &c^2
\end{vmatrix}$

$\displaystyle D=abc(b-a)(c-a)(b-c)\begin{vmatrix}
1 &a^2  &0 \\ 
0 &1  & b+c \\ 
0 &c+a  &c^2
\end{vmatrix}$

$\displaystyle D=-abc(b-a)(c-a)(b-c)(ab+bc+ca)$

Similarly,

$\begin{vmatrix}
a &a^3  &1 \\ 
b &b^3  &1 \\ 
c &c^3  &1 \\
\end{vmatrix}=(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(a+b+c)$

Now, $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\ne0$(why?) hence can be safely cancelled out